# Random position of draggable images on each new reload using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, random, position, draggable

I've figured out how to successfully make two images draggable using jquery, as you can see in this example here:
http://www.demarconia.com/kingofqueens/kingtest3.html

what I would like to do is to give the two images a unique random position on the page upon each reload. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Just give each element absolute positioning and assign a random value to the `left` and `top` attributes:

```
$('img.draggable').each(function(i,el){

    var tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*500),
        tTop  = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);

    $(el).css({position:'absolute', left: tLeft, top: tTop});

});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PEAvw/)

You can change the multiplier (500) for `tLeft` and `tTop` to give the general area you want the images to appear within.

Comment: Sorry... I'm still kind of a rookie when it comes to jquery. I tried inserting that code directly into the existing script, but it's not working. Do I need to modify that?

Comment: Here's my test page again with your code added (incorrectly on my part)

http://www.demarconia.com/kingofqueens/kingtest3.html

Comment: Syntax error, you left off the end of the ready function `});`, and make sure you add `position:absolute` to the `.draggable` CSS.

Comment: Edited answer to change the appropriate CSS in the jQuery code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm really feel like a green horn when it comes to this. I'm not sure what any of that means or how to implement it. 

where is the ready function that I should add the }); too? 





I don't think there is a css sheet for this page? I didn't upload one anyway

Comment: Wow, fast response. I swapped out the new code, but it's still not working, and now the dragging isn't working either. Where is that syntax error from before? I added a }); before your code, was that the right spot?

Comment: OK I fixed it so that it's dragging again but I still can't get your random position code to work.

Comment: The code has to be within the `{}` of the `document.ready(function(){ ...code here... });`